# Swift Optional Error when loading website through TableViewCell

Tags: swift, xcode, web, view, option-type

I have included a copy of my code below:

```
import WebKit
import UIKit

class WebsitesTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var webview: WKWebView!
    var websites = ["apple.com", "hackingwithswift.com"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return websites.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "website", for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = websites[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "browser") as? ViewController {

            let url = URL(string: "https://" + websites[indexPath.row])
            webview.load(URLRequest(url: url!))
            webview.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
            navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
        }
    }


}
```

I seem to receive the following error when running the app:

exc_bad_instruction(code=EXC_I1386-INVOP,subcode=0x0)

I am new to Swift and I think it is something to do with forcing to unwrap but I am not entirely sure. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Where does the exception occur? You can tell Xcode to break on the exception by going to the Breakpoint navigator (Cmd+7), clicking on the + in the bottom left corner, and selecting "Exception breakpoint..." Then re-run your app and it should break on the line that is causing the exception.

Comment: Thank you for your response and your help. Please see below on my reply on the next comment. I have made changes and included a copy of my code. I am trying to get the website to load when it has been selected on Table View :)

Answer (score 0):

Possible two things causing this issue.

- First can you make sure when you are retrieving your cells that you get something in your "cell" object in `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`. Use print on your cell or just a test.
- Secondly in your `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` you use `storyboard?`. Where did you instantiate it ? Is it proposed as an autocompletion solution. In general to use your storyboard, you previously need to instantiate it like this : `let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MyStoryboardName", bundle: nil)`

1st edit to unwrap url :

```
if let url = URL(string: "https://" + selectedWebsite) {
   // URL unwrap with success
   webView.load(URLRequest(url: url)) 
   webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
} else {
  // Can't get URL
}
```

Comment: https://ufile.io/bgkcx 

I have included a copy of my code to view on Xcode. I have made changes and I think I am nearly there. I am now unsure how to convert a string to a URL to load the URL when the website is selected in Table View List

Comment: Did you use the function URL(string: String) ?

Comment: I have see below

 var selectedWebsite: String?

var convertedToURL = URL(selectedWebsite)
        
let url = URL(string: "https://" + selectedWebsite)
webView.load(URLRequest(url: url)) webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true

Comment: Okay but you aren't using var convertedToURL

Comment: if I try like this 

let url = URL(string: "https://" + selectedWebsite)!
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
        webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true

It wants me to unwrap it but unsure how :/ sorry for being a pain

Comment: I edit my answer to show you how you can unwrap safely your url

Comment: I have fixed it by using var selectedWebsite: String! instead of String? .. I don't understand optionals lol

Comment: By putting an exclamation mark ! you are saying to the compiler don't worry this variable will have a value in the future. You need to check apple documentation here : https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html